# Grouping classes that share the greatest number of attributes in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe of films that are tagged with a unique set of traits. What I would like to do is find the group of films with the most similar traits to each other.

Here is a sample of the raw data:

```
sub_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Trait'], 
                      data= [['across the universe', 'drug addiction'],
                             ['across the universe', 'romantic'],
                             ['across the universe', 'trippy'],
                             ['across the universe', 'hippy'],
                             ['across the universe', 'rock & roll'],
                             ['walk the line', 'romantic'],
                             ['walk the line', 'rock & roll'],
                             ['walk the line', 'drug addiction'],
                             ['walk the line', 'rebel'],
                             ['dreamgirls', 'singing'],
                             ['dreamgirls', 'yearning'],
                             ['dreamgirls', 'drug addiction'],
                             ['rocketman', 'rock & roll'],
                             ['rocketman', 'drug addiction'],
                             ['rocketman', 'singing'],
                             ['rocketman', 'music biopic'],
                             ['rocketman', 'romantic'],
                             ])
```

What I want to see are the films across the universe, walk the line, and rocketman grouped together because, although they don't have the same number of traits, they have a greater amount common traits than dreamgirls.

Ideally, I would like to see the *clusters of films that share greater number of traits*.

I have thousands of records like this and each title has a unique number of traits so the "frequency matrix" looks something like this (cells are really just 1/0):

```
PD.crosstab(films_df['Trait'], films_df['Title'], margins=True).sort_values(by = ['All'], ascending = False)
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0):

i've come up with *a* solution. i wonder if there's a way to visualize it?

```
# create a dictionary of the films and their traits

film_dict = {}
def add_film(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        film_dict[data.iloc[i]['Title']] = data.iloc[i]['Trait']

add_film(sub_df)

# given dictionary of films and their traits, count the number of similar traits between a film and every other film
film_sims = []
def get_sim(dict):
    for film in dict:
        for other_film in dict:
            if film != other_film:
                # bind to dataframe
                similar_traits = len(set(dict[film]).intersection(set(dict[other_film])))
                new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['film', 'other_film', 'similar_traits'],
                                   data= [[film, other_film, similar_traits]])
                # append new to film_sims
                film_sims.append(new)
                # print(film, other_film)

get_sim(film_dict)
film_sims = pd.concat(film_sims)
```

this returns a dataframe like this:

[image]